# Can i use nested if statement for the code I'm writing

Tags: python-3.11

```
Length_In_Feet = float(input("Please enter the length of the room (in feet): "))

Width_In_Feet = float(input("Please enter the width of the room (in feet): "))

Amt_Of_Shade = input("What is the amount of shade the room receives?: \n \
                1.Little Shade \n \
                2.Modrate Shade \n \
                3.Aboundent Shade \n \
                Please select from the options above: ")

# Calculate the area
Room_Area_In_Square = (Width_In_Feet) * (Length_In_Feet)

BTUS_Per_Hour = 0


print("Air Conditioning Window Unit Cooling Capacity")

if Amt_Of_Shade == 2:
    if Room_Area_In_Square <= 250:
        BTUS_Per_Hour += 5500
        print(BTUS_Per_Hour)
    

print(f"\
    Room Area (in square feet): {`Room_Area_In_Square`}\n \
    Amount of Shade: {`Amt_Of_Shade`}\n \
    BTU’s Per Hour needed: {BTUS_Per_Hour:.2f}")
```

I'm expecting my code to give me this same output:

- Please enter the length of the room (in feet): **15.5**
- Please enter the width of the room (in feet): **10**
- What is the amount of shade that this room receives: 
  1. Little Shade 
  2. Moderate Shade 
  3. Abundant Shade 
  Please select from the options above: **3**
- Air Conditioning Window Unit Cooling Capacity
- Room Area (in square feet): 155.0
- Amount of Shade: Abundant
- BTU’s Per Hour needed: 4,950

Comment: You are asking if you can use nested `if` statements. The answer is of course yes. But the question is, 1. what do you want to get when using them and 2. where do you want to use them. Maybe you might not nested statements at all.